# How to make my menu list on the top page?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

I'm new in web development and currently learning react tutorial from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2UBjN5ER4s&list=PL7vENmfab_gem35_YWjoLbJIWE0r5gD5i&index=2&t=258s&ab_channel=BrianDesign) and my list menu is not on top of the page:

[image]

how can i move the list menu on the topside of the page?
I tried to download and run the code from github and it appears the list on the bottom of the page.

here's my code, thankyou in advance.

JS:

```
function Navbar() {
const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
const [button, setButton] = useState(true);
const menuClicked = () => setClick(!click);
const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);
const showButton = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 960) {
        setButton(false);
    } else {
        setButton(true);
    }
};
useEffect(() => {
    showButton()
}, []);

window.addEventListener('resize', showButton);
return (
    <>
        <nav className='navbar'>
            <div className='navbar-container'>
                <Link to='/' className='navbar-logo' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                    TRVL
                    <i class='fab fa-typo3' />
                </Link>
                <div className='menu-icon' onClick={menuClicked}>
                    <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
                </div>
                <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                    <li className='nav-item'>
                        <Link to='/' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                            Home
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className='nav-item'>
                        <Link
                            to='/services'
                            className='nav-links'
                            onClick={closeMobileMenu}
                        >
                            Services
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className='nav-item'>
                        <Link
                            to='/products'
                            className='nav-links'
                            onClick={closeMobileMenu}
                        >
                            Products
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link
                            to='/sign-up'
                            className='nav-links-mobile'
                            onClick={closeMobileMenu}
                        >
                            Sign Up
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                {button && <Button buttonStyle='btn--outline'>SIGN UP</Button>}
            </div>
        </nav>
    </>
)
}

export default Navbar
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {


background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(28, 27, 27) 0%, rgb(26, 23, 23) 100%);
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  max-width: 1500px;
}

.navbar-logo {
  color: #fff;
  justify-self: start;
  margin-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.fa-typo3 {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60vw;
  justify-content: end;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.nav-item {
  height: 80px;
}

.nav-links {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-links:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.fa-bars {
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-links-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .NavbarItems {
    position: relative;
  }

  .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }

  .nav-menu.active {
    background: #242222;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .nav-links {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }

  .nav-links:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #242424;
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  .navbar-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(25%, 50%);
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .fa-times {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .nav-links-mobile {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2rem auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 80%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  }

  .nav-links-mobile:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #242424;
    transition: 250ms;
  }
}
```

Comment: Paste entire component please

Comment: @KonradLinkowski check my updated code please

Comment: You have `NavbarItems` in your css but not in component